# Is it possible to have a HasManyThrough relationship that's deeper than two levels?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have the following models:

```
Product
BaseProduct
BaseCode
Series
```

Each of them is something of a separate entity, but they're related.

`Product` has a foreign key to `BaseProduct`, `BaseProduct` has a foreign key to `BaseCode` and `BaseCode` has a foreign key to `Series`.

I have specified a method within my `BaseCode` model so I can select all of the `Products` that are related to that particular `BaseCode`:

```php
public function Products()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough('Product', 'BaseProduct', 'BaseCodeId', 'BaseProductId');
}
```

`BaseCodeId` is the PK for the `BaseCode` and the FK in `BaseProduct` that is pointing to that PK, and `BaseProductId` is the PK for `BaseProduct`, and in the `Product` table, there's a FK that points to it.

This is all well and good, and works just dandy for me.

I'd like to go one level further though, and define something like the following in my `Series` model:

```php
public function Products()
{
    //It's here that I'd have no idea what to do - is there something like a three-level deep "hasManyThroughThrough" or something?
    return $this->BaseProducts()-> /* and then whatever I'd do here to get the products */
}

public function BaseProducts()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough('BaseProduct', 'BaseCode', 'SeriesId', 'BaseCodeId');
}
```

How do I get all of the `Product`s associated with `Series` like that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am somewhat new to 4.1, but it looks as though `hasManyThrough()` was not designed for the types of relationships you are looking for and is really just a shortcut for two level deep eager loading.

Try traditional eager loading instead...

`$data = Product::with('BaseProduct.BaseCode.Series');`

You will need to make sure the relationships are setup in your models as necessary and instead of calling model names, you will want to call the methods that are defining the relationships.

Also obviously, be sure your models know what the primary keys are by using `protected $primaryKey = 'SeriesID'` etc...

Comment: Thanks sir.  After a good bit of heavy digging and messing around, I haven't been able to get Eloquent to bend the way I'd like it to, and have come to the same conclusion.

Answer (score 1):

I created a `HasManyThrough` relationship with unlimited levels: [Repository on GitHub](https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-has-many-deep)

After the installation, you can use it like this:

```php
class Series extends Model {
    use \Staudenmeir\EloquentHasManyDeep\HasRelationships;

    public function products() {
        return $this->hasManyDeep(Product::class,
            [BaseCode::class, BaseProduct::class],
            ['SeriesId', 'BaseCodeId', 'BaseProductId']
        );
    }
}
```