# Multiple level hasManyThrough relationship with Eloquent

Tags: php, eloquent, relationship

I'm using `Eloquent`  in my PHP application and struggling with a `hasManyThrough` relationship.

Here's my structure :

```
Company 
   id
   name

Admin
   id
   company_id
   name

Offer
   id
   admin_id
   name

Application
   id
   offer_id
   candidat_id
```

Each `Admin`  is part of a `Company` and can post `Offer`'s, and the candidats can make an `Application` on that offer.

**I'm trying to fetch all the applications that have been made on offers that have been started by admins of that company.**

I've tried using the `hasManyThrough` relationship in my `Company` model, like so :

```
public function applications()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough("Application", "Offer");
}
```

but I get the following error :

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'offers.entreprise_id' in 'field list' (SQL: select `applications`.*, `offers`.`entreprise_id` from `applications` inner join `offers` on `offers`.`id` = `applications`.`offer_id` where `offers`.`entreprise_id` in (1))
```

Which makes sense, since it's thinking that the `Offer` is listed to the `Company` and not to the `Admin`.

How can I set it up so that it will look for the `Admin`'s of that company, without having to fetch all the admins of the company and then looping through them, getting all the applications for each admins?

This would work, but it seems like a tedious way of doing it when Eloquent provides these relationships that make our lives easier. Is there a more elegant way of achieving what I want?

Comment: Have you seen this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21594290/is-it-possible-to-have-a-hasmanythrough-relationship-thats-deeper-than-two-leve , and could the approach in that answer possibly work for you?

Answer (score 0):

There is no native relationship for this case.

I created a `HasManyThrough` relationship with unlimited levels: [Repository on GitHub](https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-has-many-deep)

After the installation, you can use it like this:

```php
class Company extends Model {
    use \Staudenmeir\EloquentHasManyDeep\HasRelationships;

    public function applications() {
        return $this->hasManyDeep(Application::class, [Admin::class, Offer::class]);
    }
}
```