# HasMany Relationships as combined collection

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a Merchant model, this Merchant model has many Categories and each Category has many Products.

Now for my Product index I would like to list all Products for a given Merchant.

```
$categories = Category::where('merchant_id', 1);

foreach ($categories as $category) {
    $products[] = Product::where('category_id', $category->id);
}
```

This code would give me an array of collections of all the Products for the Merchant with id = 1.

How can I combine the collections so I can pass them to my view?

```
return view('products.index', compact('products'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need here is a `HasManyThrough` relationship between your Merchent and your products I think:

```
class Merchant extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get all of the products for the merchant.
     */
    public function products()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Product', 'App\Category');
    }
}
```

Then, you should be able to retrieve all the products for a given merchant using `$merchant->products`

Here is the documentation for that if you need more informations:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through

Good luck with it, and I hope it helps!

Comment: What if I need a 3rd relation? Let's say that each Product has many Accessories, and I need a relation to all Accessories from the Merchant model.

Comment: Good question, and sadly, there is nothing written for that, you should use something else... You can see this question for some hint: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21594290/is-it-possible-to-have-a-hasmanythrough-relationship-thats-deeper-than-two-leve

Comment: That article might interest you as well: https://softonsofa.com/laravel-querying-any-level-far-relations-with-simple-trick/